# Delete all files in a folder that doesn't have certain name

Tags: python

So I have about 1200 folders with different content in each. In all of them there is one file that has a specific name, let's call it `data.txt`.

Now, due to lack of hard drive space I need to remove/delete all data in each folder that is not that particular file, i.e. `data.txt`.

Is this possible to do in python ? If so, how ? :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Check out `glob`...

Answer (score 0):

Try This ( with OS module only ) :

```
import os

your_target_folder = "."
your_target_file_name = "data.txt"


for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(your_target_folder):

    for items in filenames:

        file_full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, items))

        try:

            if items == your_target_file_name:
                os.remove(file_full_path)

        except:
            print("Error On " + str(file_full_path))

print("Done")
```